# Where to find discord.py bot in self attributes in order to assign roles

Tags: python, oop, discord, discord.py

I am the owner of a Discord server that doesn't have too many people so  I want them to introduce themselves so I can keep track of who's who. Upon joining, members only have access to a `#introductions` channel. When they type in their name, they are given the `Member` role.

There isn't any `discord.py` function that does this, so I have to split this into two parts: first, get the author of the most recent message, and, second, assign them the `Member` role. The first part is not difficult at all, but the second part throws me an error.

**Code**

```py
class UtilBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self, *, command_prefix, name):
        commands.Bot.__init__(
            self, command_prefix=command_prefix, self_bot=False)
        with open(r'.\docs\channels.csv') as channels:
            channel_ids = list(csv.reader(channels, delimiter='\t'))
            for i, item in enumerate(channel_ids):
                channel_ids[i] = [int(item[0]), item[1]]
            self.channels = dict(channel_ids)
        self.channel_commands = {
            '#introductions': self.introduction,
            '#dev-build': self.introduction} #Allow for feature testing
        self.name = name

    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f"Utils is running")

    async def on_message(self, message):
        channel = self.channels[message.channel.id]
        print(channel)
        try:
            self.channel_commands[channel](message)
        except KeyError:
            pass

    def introduction(self, message):
        member = message.author
        role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Member")
        self.add_roles(member, role)

    def dev_build(self, message):
        print(f'{message.author.name} ({self.channels[message.channel.id]})')
        print(message.content)
```

**Error**

```
AttributeError: 'UtilBot' object has no attribute 'add_roles'
```

I am asking both how to fix this error while maintaining an OOP framework and if there is an alternative method that completes the same task. If I know where to find the self attribute that corresponds to the bot I can easily fix this, but when looking at `self.__dict__`, I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `self.add_roles(member, role)`, try `member.add_roles(role)`

Comment: Yeah that was pretty much the only thing. I was looking at answers for before the discord.py rewrite so obviously it wouldn’t work.